# Exporting terms and meta from woocommerce in same query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make an optimized query to export products from a woocommerce site. What i'm trying to achieve is to have a term and a meta value reported in the same row with the product, but i'm having weird errors. The query i reached so far is this

```
SELECT p.*, t.name brand, pm_ss.meta_value stock_status 
FROM wp_posts as p, wp_term_relationships as r, wp_terms as t 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as x ON x.term_id=t.term_id AND x.taxonomy='product_brand' 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm_ss ON pm_ss.post_id=p.ID AND pm_ss.meta_key='_stock_status' 
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'product' 
AND r.term_taxonomy_id=x.term_taxonomy_id AND pm_ss.meta_value!='outofstock'
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
 unknown column 'p.id' in on clause
```

while obviously the column name is right. Since this is also a generic query issue, i'm adding some info for those unfamiliar with wordpress table structure. The main table is `wp_posts` which has an `ID` column as identifier. Then there are the other tables:

```
TABLE wp_posts
  ID : identifier of the table
  post_content : content of the post
  post_title : title of the post
  post_type : type of the post
  post_status : status of the post
  ... other column not useful for the question

TABLE: wp_postmeta - contains all post meta
  post_id : refers to wp_posts.ID
  meta_key : identifier of the meta tag
  meta_value : value of the meta tag

TABLE: wp_terms - contains all terms
  term_id : identifier of the term
  name : name of the term, in this case it contains the brand name

TABLE: wp_term_relationships - contains link between terms and posts
  object_id : refers to wp_posts.ID
  term_taxonomy_id : refers to wp_terms.terms_id

TABLE: wp_term_taxonomy - contains the description of the specific term
  term_id : refers to wp_terms.terms_id
  taxonomy : specify the use of the specific term, in this case i'm looking for product_brand
```

Also, someone have an indea on how to improve the query and maybe to search to 2 different type of terms in the same query? Thanks

Comment: Please add all tables, because nothing is clear.  p.ID and unknown column 'p.id'  don't correspond. or you use a different query

Comment: I've added the definition of wp_posts table, it was the only table missing

Comment: thx but i can still not find p.id in your select statement. So you shouldn't get the error message. Post the **complete** error message.

Comment: 4th row of the select `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm_ss ON pm_ss.post_id=p.ID` and i have posted the complete error message, that's all i get